# Is there any way to force django run some finishing code before exit?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am running a server program with django, 
I want to run some code before and after the server running.
Where can I put those code?

```
<run function a here>
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
^C
<run function b here>
```

I have tried to a `print('hello')` in `app/__init__.py`, but found that it runs for twice. Why?

Comment: Is this for development server only? Do you want to `run function b` after `^C` only, or after any server failure? Note that in some cases your function may not be called (e.g. KILL signal, memory error, maybe something else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do think it's not a good idea to run Django app with `runserver` or similar.
So your question can be "How to quit Django App gracefully".

Commonly we run Django in production environment with `gunicorn` or similar WSGI apps. You will not know when and how it quits.

So we may catch signal `SIG_INT` and `SIG_TERM` for gracefully quiting.
e.g.

```py
import signal

def quit_gracefully():
   print('quit')

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, quit_gracefully)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, quit_gracefully)
```

ref to this doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html

Comment: I have tried you solution, ```sys.exit()``` is needed for quit the program.
For your approach, where should I put initial code?

Comment: I usually use settings.py, some initialization codes can be put here. Also, can use `AppConfig`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/.    All these has limitations, but they can solve my 99% needs.

Comment: Another problem: I saw two ```hello``` printed at the end while I only put one

Comment: sorry, just see this. maybe you already solved it. just in case not yet, try using different functions for each signal. and print different messages to debug. there might be some duplicated signals or function triggered twice or etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide your own runserver command and override django's. Assuming your app is named `polls` like in the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project), then you need to create this structure:

```
polls/
    ...
    |management/
        |__init__.py
        |commands/
             |__init__.py
             |runserver.py
```

This creates the python modules "polls.management" and "polls.management.commands", which is where Django is looking for [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/).

```py
# Put in polls/management/commands/runserver.py
from django.core.management.commands.runserver import Command as RunServer


class Command(RunServer):
    def inner_run(self, *args, **options):
        self.pre_start()
        super().inner_run(*args, **options)
        self.pre_quit()

    def pre_start(self):
        # do your stuff

    def pre_quit(self):
        # do your stuff
```

If you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, you need to put your app before `django.contrib.staticfiles` and change the import:

```py
from django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver import Command as RunServer
```

So if your app is `polls` INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py should become:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # other apps
    "polls",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    # other apps
]
```

Comment: where should I put the folder ```management```? I have both tried beside ```manage.py``` and inside the app folder. but nothing happened. Or anything I need to do with ```manage.py```?

Comment: Inside one of the folders that is in `INSTALLED_APPS`. If you followed the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) then `mysite` is a project and contains manage.py and `polls` is an app that is in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. You need to put it inside the equivalent of `polls`.

Comment: Ok, one more thing I just found is I cannot name this file as runserver.py which overlapped with original command

Comment: Yes, you can cause you want to override the original command. What isn't working? Do you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes.```'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', ......```

Comment: `self.pre_quit()` is useless because inner run has `sys.exit`